# they came in groups of five

Tags: riddle

I got this one from my nephew, and I am still seeking the answer. What is it?

The Riddle is for you to solve
they came in groups of five,

The Birds and the bush began to burn,
From school he televised,

Nicholas trapped inside himself,
you must find the light,

Over the bathtub the siblings burnt,
Thus began the global fight

Comment: Where did you get this riddle from?

Comment: Welcome to PSE @Pankaj Sharma. As bobble asked, you need to provide the source for this puzzle if it is not yours. Otherwise it will get closed.

Comment: Hey Bobble, my nephew asked me this puzzle and I can't make head or tails of it for the  last 14 hours. Worst part is that nothing springs to mind, can't even get a thread for a change.